# The meaning of double curly braces (`{{ ... }}`) in LaTex?

Tags: latex, bibtex

While compiling sources for my thesis, I noticed that in a *.bib file, the title was written using `{{Insert title here}}` and copied this in my *.tex file: `\section{Recognizing {{Human Daily Activities From Accelerometer Signal}} ... }`.

I wondered what it would do. After compiling, I saw no difference. Then, I tried using only a single curly brace, e.g., `{Insert title here}`, and this also showed no difference.

On documentation, I could not really find any ruling about this in LaTex. Does anyone know what they signify? Do they have something to do with non-breaking spaces? Line breaks?

Thanks :)

I only checked the results using my own two eyes. So maybe there is a difference in the pdf or the characters itself.

Neither the double nor the single brackets did anything for me.

Comment: Looks like markers that either another program or the author should replace

Comment: Cross-site duplicate [Different behavior of double curly braces from single curly braces and quotation marks in correction of letter cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294870/242828)

Comment: @Robert No, that's ordinary bibtex syntax.

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327386/242828, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109064/242828, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255343/242828, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629260/242828

Comment: @Brian61354270, I think that your "Cross-site duplicate" provides answers to the *.bib case. I, however, have inserted the code in LaTex itself, trying to see what the characters mean in *.tex. I do not think that the cross-site URL answers that question?

Comment: @StudentCS My bad, read your question too quickly. In LaTeX itself, double curly braces don't have special meaning; it's just single curly braces nested twice. As for what curly braces themselves mean, that's probably best answered in [What is a token?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104023/242828)

Comment: @Brian61354270, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. (I can accept your last comment as an answer and give you credit if you want to post it as an answer :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double curly braces don't have any special meaning in LaTeX; it's just single curly braces nested twice. As for what curly braces themselves mean, see

- [What is a token?  - TeX & LaTex StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104023/242828)
- [How are curly braces used? - TeX & LaTex StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267412/242828)